# Should we sync failed incremental backup?

Tags: marklogic

I maintain a backup of the ML backup using unix `rsync` job. If an incremental backup fails, should I rsync after that regardless of whether incr. backup failed or not? Or should I add a check to sync only successful incremental backups?
Does markLogic clean erases failed backups from the mounted directory?

Answer (score 0):

You should only rsync the completed incremental backups.  If a backup did not complete, then it will likely fail the validation step that occurs as part of the restore process.

It should also automatically delete the failed backups, but this can easily be verified the next time an incremental backup fails.

Comment: Why would it fail the validation steps that occurs as part of the restore process if the failed incremental backups are cleaned by MarkLogic? The idea is to mimic the entire backup directory structure so we should sync everything that is in MLbackup directory. Isn't it ?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, it would not occur.  The MarkLogic database backup initiates a full set of forests level backups.  The individual forest backups can complete and be static on disk prior to the overall backup completing.  If they are copied or write protected in some way, then you could have an invalid backup.